# Magento - Can clients order as guest even when they have an account

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, customer, guest-checkout

We use magento 1.8.1CE.

Customers have the option to check out as guest or make an account.

But is it also possible for customers who have an account to check out without logging in?
And if yes, how can i set this up?

Answer (score 2):

they can checkout as guests and you don't have to setup anything

some onestepcheckout extensions send alerts to a client asking to login if they recognize his email already in the system but if you are using default magento 6step checkout it won't say a thing.

Comment: not on our website .... We often get a call that clients cann't place the order, and when they log-in they can.

Comment: well that is probably some 3rd party extension messing you up. default magento 1.x install lets client do guest checkout without a glitch. could you try and checkout as guest being a client? any error messages?

Comment: guest checkout it self is no problem. But when a customer has ordered before, and made an account with that order they have to use that account to be able to order. (when using the same mailbox)

Comment: not necessarily. just install default magento 1.x on your test box, create an account, checkout as client, then checkout as guest with the same email and see for yourself. or believe me.

Comment: i believe you .... i guess i have to contact my quick checkout extension provider

Comment: here you go. you have quick checkout extension. that is the problem. get a hold of its vendor and ask for help.